# I can not get python to print a position from a lists/arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am unsure how to print what is at an index position in an array i.e.

```
array1 = ["1","2","3"]
```

if I wanted the program to print `3` what do i do?

Comment: Please consider looking at the [python introduction](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), especially the section on lists. It will answer this an *many* other questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
array1=["1","2","3"]
print(array1[2])
```

so index start from 0 so list will always haves length-1 index

Answer (score 1):

Index in python starts from zero. If you want to print “3” in above list, just do `print(array1[2])` as “3” is at index 2.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about this; one way is to index it positively, and the other is to index it negatively. Observe:

```
>>> array1 = ["1","2","3"]
>>> print(array1[2])
3
>>> print(array1[-1])
3
```

The index `-1` returns the last element of an array.

Comment: Why have you changed the name  of the array from “array1” to “barray1” in the question? Just curious.

Comment: @MuhammadMohsinKhan OMG, my blunder! It was a mistake.